# шлейф от изображения при его перемещении с помощью setLocation

Tags: java, swing, gui

Доброго времени суток.

Задача следующая: реализовать перемещение изображения при нажатии клавиш W, A, S, D.

Я попытался реализовать её следующим образом:

Объект этого класса я и пытаюсь передвигать с помощью setLocation()

```
package viewPG;

import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import modelPG.IMove;
import modelPG.Model;

class Person extends JPanel implements IMove{

    private Image image; 
    private Model model;

    Person(Model model) {
        this.model = model;

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(View.path + "wizard.png"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }

        setSize(model.getWidthPerson(), model.getHeightPerson());
        setOpaque(false);
        model.addMoveListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    } 

    //Этот метод вызывается из другого потока
    public void newPoz(int x, int y) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setLocation(x, y);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Вот класс добавляющий все объекты во фрейм:

```
package viewPG;

import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import modelPG.Model;

public class View extends JPanel{

    private Model model;
    private Container container;
    private Map map;
    private Person person;
    static String path = "D:/mapPG/src/graphicsPG/";

    public View(Model model, Container container) {
        this.model = model;
        this.container = container;

        map = new Map(model);
        person = new Person(model);

        container.add(map);
        container.add(person);
    }

}
```

Если не добавлять объект Map во фрейм:

```
container.add(map);
```

То никакого шлейфа от движущегося изображения не появляется (хотя перемещение дерганое). Но если добавить, то тогда появляется шлейф. Никак не могу понять причину.

Вот код класса Map:

```
package viewPG;

import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import modelPG.mapPG.MapObject;
import modelPG.Model;

class Map extends JPanel{

    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int countCellInRow;
    private int countCellInColumn;
    private Image[][] images;
    private Model model;

    Map(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.width = model.getWidthMap();
        this.height = model.getHeightMap();
        this.countCellInRow = model.getCountCellInRow();
        this.countCellInColumn = model.getCountCellInColumn();

        setSize(width, height);

        images = new Image[countCellInColumn][countCellInRow];

        assembleMap();
    }

   //часть кода пропущена

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for(int y = 0; y < countCellInColumn; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < countCellInRow; x++) {
                if(images[y][x] != null) {
                    int pozX = model.getCellInRowAndColumn(x, y).CENTER_X 
                              - images[y][x].getWidth(null) / 2;
                    int pozY = model.getCellInRowAndColumn(x, y).CENTER_Y
                              - images[y][x].getHeight(null);
                    g.drawImage(images[y][x], pozX, pozY, null);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Необходимо в классе Map, в методе paintComponent() вызывать paintComponent() супер класса:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);//эта строчка устраняет проблему
        for(int y = 0; y < countCellInColumn; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < countCellInRow; x++) {
                if(images[y][x] != null) {
                    int pozX = model.getCellInRowAndColumn(x, y).CENTER_X 
                              - images[y][x].getWidth(null) / 2;
                    int pozY = model.getCellInRowAndColumn(x, y).CENTER_Y
                              - images[y][x].getHeight(null);
                    g.drawImage(images[y][x], pozX, pozY, null);
                }
            }
         }
     }
```